# How can I use my static variable in other `*.cpp` file?

Tags: c++

I made files, and their names are

- `main.cpp`
- `able.hpp`
- `able.cpp`
- `ability.hpp`
- `ability.cpp`

And in `ability.hpp` file, there is

```cpp
static int num_abilities;
```

I don't know how to use `num_abilities` in `able.cpp`. I did:

```cpp
#include "ability.hpp"
```

Also, but I can't use this static int.
What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "I can`t use this static int"? Please provide your error message

Comment: Replace `static` with `extern`, and choose one cpp file where you write the global definition of that variable (whithout using `static`).

Comment: `extern` keyword will make the variable global, so use it instead of static.

Comment: You need an variable with an external linkage, something like `inline` variables in C++17 or variables with `extern` in previous C++17 standard.

Comment: My error message was "Use of undeclared identifier 'num_abilities'". But I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`static` global variables are file scope by default in C++.

Do:

1. Change it to `extern` in the header file
2. Add a definition (without static) in a cpp file

You can then use your global variable across multiple files.